# Как составить запрос ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть модель `User` и зависимая модель `Friend`, которая, кроме всего прочего содержит `u_id` - `user_id` который этот друг имеет как пользователь - член модели `User`. Как получить друзей всех друзей (хочу определить есть ли я сам в этом списке - взаимность дружбы)?

Поскольку у меня есть `u_id`, я думал, что все будет просто: сначала я нахожу своих `@profile.friends.all` потом в `User` всех этих `friends` по `u_id`, а потом - `friends` этих `User` (ну а там уже себя нахожу или не нахожу).
Но - никак не смог продвинуться дальше понимания, все варианты не работают.

Comment: Немного непонятно, не могли бы представить миграции этих двух моделей и постановку зависимостей в самих моделях?

Comment: Зависимость простая: User has_many Friend. Просто есть набор пользователей, которые могут быть друзьями друг-друга (т.е. входят и в User и в Friend). Чтобы упростить нахождение пользователя в User по его записи в Friend я добавил u_id - id, который этот пользователь имеет в User.                                                         create_table "friends", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "u_id"
  end

Comment: Впрочем, я уже близок к решению.                                        userfromfriends = User.all.where(id: friends.select(:u_id))
     friendsofusers = Friend.where(user_id: userfromfriends.select(:id))
     mutualfriends = friendsofusers.where(u_id: params[:id]). Надо еще немного подумать.

Comment: @ВалентинАндреев добавляйте существенные детали прямо в вопрос.

Comment: К сожалению, для определения взаимности дружбы надо присоединить (join) friends к самой себе. К сожалению, потому что AR вам тут чистого решения не даст: либо с куском SQL, либо с Arel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*С радостью сообщаю, что в комментариях я почти ошибся.*

То есть, такой **запрос** написать действительно непросто, но с этим можно справиться с помощью **ассоциаций**. К сожалению, решение не очень чистое. Не стоит слишком много хотеть от языка запросов ActiveRecord, он не предназначен для сложных случаев.

Трюк состоит из рекурсивного `has_many :through`. Рекурсивного, т. к. ассоциация связывает записи с записями **того же типа**.

Я приведу изолированный пример. Внешние ключи в нём, вероятно, не будут соответствовать вашему случаю, доработайте под себя.

```rb
class Friend
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :u, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :through_friends, class_name: self.name,
                             primary_key: :u_id,
                             foreign_key: :user_id
end

class User
  has_many :friends
end
```

Имея такие ассоциации, можно сделать следующий запрос:

```
puts User.joins(friends: :through_friends).to_sql
```

Это выведет запрос, содержащий self-join (самосоединение) таблицы `friends`. Причём сначала она будет без алиаса, а потом с алиасом.

> **Здесь используется недокументированная деталь реализации!** Алиас, похоже, генерируется детерминированно. Во всяком случае, в каждой конкретной версии Rails можно ожидать, что он не поменяется, но чтобы не получить внезапных багов, используйте тесты, обновляйтесь осторожно, или даже сделайте *на уровне класса* (чтобы падало при инициализации) предупреждение:
>
> ```
> unless ActiveRecord.version.to_s = '4.2.6' #или какая у вас там версия сейчас
>   raise NotImplementedError, 'implementation detail from another version'
> end
> ```
>
> Или каким-нибудь более продвинутым способом, на ваш вкус.

Вам нужно взять этот алиас (у меня это оказался `through_friends_friends`) и наложить по нему условия примерно так:

```
User.joins(friends: :through_friends).where(
  through_friends_friends: { u_id: @user.id }
)
```

В теории, должен получиться список "друзей друзей" `@user`а. Чтобы не получить дубликаты (из-за `JOIN`'ов), стоит добавить `.distinct`. А если вы проверяете только дружбу, а не достаёте пользователей, можно исключить из рассмотрения `User`'а и работать сразу с `Friend`:

```
@user.friends.joins(:through_friends).where(
  through_friends_friends: { u_id: @user.id }
).exists?
```

**Экспериментируйте.**